# String rearrangment in R

Tags: regex, r, string, gsub, strsplit

I have a long list of names of city and its province name. This is partial list of my data

```
data <- c('Ranchi_Capital_State_Jharkhand', 'Bokaro_State_Jharkhand', 'Tata Nagar_State_Jharkhand', 'Ramgarh_State_Jharkhand',
      'Pune_State_Maharashtra', 'Mumbai_Capital_State_Maharashtra', 'Nagpur_State_Maharashtra')
```

I want to arrange it such that State should come first, like this `State_Jharkhand_Bokaro`. If city is a capital then `State_Jharkhand_Capital_Ranchi`. Also note that city name or state name may have single string or more than one string (eg Tata Nagar).

What is most efficient way to do it, (without using any loop)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the below `gsub` function.

```
> data <- c('Ranchi_Capital_State_Jharkhand', 'Bokaro_State_Jharkhand', 'Tata Nagar_State_Jharkhand', 'Ramgarh_State_Jharkhand',
+           'Pune_State_Maharashtra', 'Mumbai_Capital_State_Maharashtra', 'Nagpur_State_Maharashtra')
> gsub("^(?:(.*?)(_Capital))?(.*?)_(State.*)", "\\4\\2_\\1\\3", data)
[1] "State_Jharkhand_Capital_Ranchi"   "State_Jharkhand_Bokaro"          
[3] "State_Jharkhand_Tata Nagar"       "State_Jharkhand_Ramgarh"         
[5] "State_Maharashtra_Pune"           "State_Maharashtra_Capital_Mumbai"
[7] "State_Maharashtra_Nagpur"
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/hM5nC9/1)

Comment: Thanks Avinash, but could u please modify it. Actually somewhere its Capital_1 and Somewhere Capital_2

Comment: post an example here along with the expected output.

Comment: suppose instead of capital there is capital_1 and Capital_2 and I want
State_Jharkhand_Capital_1_Ranchi, State_Jharkhand_Capital_2_Jhumari_Tilaiya

Comment: @Rajan, please edit your *question* to include the types of data that should be considered. Also, why do you want the output to be a single string? Why not a `list` or a `data.frame`?

Comment: try `gsub("^(?:(.*?)(_Capital(?:_\\d+)?))?(.*?)_(State.*)", "\\4\\2_\\1\\3", data)`

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't really use much regex, but is mostly based on the expected position of the information. Split the strings by "_" and then reorder them as required:

```
data
# [1] "Ranchi_Capital_State_Jharkhand"   "Bokaro_State_Jharkhand"          
# [3] "Tata Nagar_State_Jharkhand"       "Ramgarh_State_Jharkhand"         
# [5] "Pune_State_Maharashtra"           "Mumbai_Capital_State_Maharashtra"
# [7] "Nagpur_State_Maharashtra"  

A <- strsplit(data, "_", TRUE)
sapply(A, function(x) {
  if (length(x) == 3) {
    paste(x[c(2, 3, 1)], collapse = "_")
  } else if (length(x) == 4) {
    paste(x[c(3, 4, 2, 1)], collapse = "_")
  } else {
    stop("unexpected length")
  }
})
# [1] "State_Jharkhand_Capital_Ranchi"   "State_Jharkhand_Bokaro"          
# [3] "State_Jharkhand_Tata Nagar"       "State_Jharkhand_Ramgarh"         
# [5] "State_Maharashtra_Pune"           "State_Maharashtra_Capital_Mumbai"
# [7] "State_Maharashtra_Nagpur"
```

I don't know if using `sapply` breaks your requirement of "without using any loop" though.

Comment: what if I have unexpected length but still wants arrangement